# C# обращение к элементу массива неизвестного размера

Tags: c#, массивы

`exp` - массив элементов типа `object`. как обратиться к определенном обьекту если заранее не известно какие именно и сколько обьектов в массиве

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(export));
exp = (export)xs.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: Поясните ваш вопрос, что есть "определенный объект", как вы его определяете.

Comment: что за класс `export`? _exp - массив элементов типа object_ - нет, `exp` - это объект класса `export`

Answer (score 2):

[Массивы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) в C# представляют собой последовательность нескольких переменных одного типа.

> Типы массива являются ссылочными типами, производными от абстрактного базового типа Array. Поскольку этот тип реализует IEnumerable и IEnumerable, в C# во всех массивах можно использовать итерацию foreach.

Оператор [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) повторяет группу вложенных операторов для каждого элемента массива или коллекции объектов, реализующих интерфейс System.Collections.IEnumerable или System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.

Вы десериализуете документ XML используя [XmlSerializer.Deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx) объекта. В строке кода:

```
exp = (export)xs.Deserialize(stream);

// чтобы это был массив, нужно написать так: 
new XmlSerializer(typeof(export[])); // где export - это тип
exp = (export[])xs.Deserialize(stream);
```

Вы получаете массив элементов заданного типа (при успешной десериализации). Этот массив поддается правилам работы с массивами в C#. Чтобы узнать количество элементов массива можно воспользоваться свойством [Array.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) (`exp.Length`) - получает общее число элементов во всех измерениях массива Array.

Таким образом Вы можете обратиться к любому элементу Вашего массива.

**1. Перебрать все элементы Вашего массива с помощью [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):**

---

```
foreach (var element in exp)             
{
    //...
}
```

**2. Обратиться по индексу к элементу в цикле [for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ch45axte.aspx):**

---

```
for (int index = 0; index < exp.Length; index++)
{
    // var element = exp[index];
}
```

**3. Обратиться по индексу, соблюдая условие:**

---

```
int index = 2;
if(index < exp.Length)
    var element = exp[index];
```